# jQuery cross domain form Submit error

Tags: jquery, post, cross-domain, payment-gateway

I have a global ajax error handler set up

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('There has been an error processing your request.');
        }
    }
});
```

I am trying to submit a hidden form to an external payment gateway

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Pay", new { invoiceId = Model.Id })',
    success: function (html) {
        $('#paymentFormContainer').html(html);
        $('#paymentFormContainer').find('form').submit();
    }
});
```

The form appears to submit OK, I see the posted data in Fiddler, but the global ajax error callback fires.

Inspecting the error does not provide any clues.

```
XMLHttpRequest: Object
error: undefined
errorThrown: ""
textStatus: "error"
```

I'm wondering if this is a cross domain posting issue?

I am using Chrome, have not tried other browsers yet.

Comment: Chrome will let you know if it's a cross-domain issue in the console log. Can you give an example of your URL? If you see the data posted in Fiddler, what *response* do you get?

Comment: Nothing in the console log. Url is `https://test.barclaycardsmartpay.com/hpp/pay.shtml`

Comment: But is that Url the one returned from `Url.Action`?

Comment: No the `Url.Action` is internal. It returns the form as a partial. If I comment out the jQuery `.submit()` line I am able to submit the form manually without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can't use an XMLHttpRequest object to make a request to a different domain that is not the host of the originating page.

As a hacky workaround, you can make your AJAX call a script on your server that proxies the request to where you want it to go.  Another option is to manipulate iframes and a client JS callback to get the desired result.

Comment: He is already posting to his own server. `@Url.Action` returns a relative URL, so he is not directly calling cross-domain.

Comment: But his callback grabs a form and calls submit().  If that form's action is on an external site the Ajax callback will not submit the form.

Comment: Could you point me to anything describing how to proxy the request in MVC? My google skills are failing.

Comment: I am not a jQuery MVC expert - but the general idea is to (1) write a server side script {php, python, etc.} and place on your domain (2) have that script take the incoming request, read the post data and construct an outgoing post to the desired cross domain site (3) have your callback submit the form which has an action set to your new server side script, not the 3rd party site.